# Does Moq mocking library for .NET 3.5 work with mono?

Tags: c#, mono, moq, monodevelop

I'm trying to use Moq on a Mono / .NET 3.5 Project using MonoDevelop for MacOS X

I've tried the sample C# code:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup((foo => foo.DoSomething("ping"))).Returns(true);
```

With IFoo beeing:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    bool DoSomething(string a);
}
```

But I keep getting the following compiler errors on the mock.Setup line:

```
    Error CS1660: Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action<Test.IFoo>>' (CS1660) (Test)
    Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Moq.Mock<Test.IFoo>.Setup(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action<Test.IFoo>>)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (Test)
    Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `anonymous method' expression to type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action<Test.IFoo>>' (CS1503) (Test)
```

Am I doing something wrong or it´s just that Mono is not yet ready for Moq?

Comment: Have you added a reference to  System.Core

Comment: Using expressions seems to work fine for me when using Mono C# compiler version 2.8.1.0.

Comment: Adding System.Core did it, thank you Preet.

Comment: @Preet, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: This works for me on linux with mono 2.10.6

Answer (score 0):

Like said in [Preet Sangha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30225/preet-sangha)'s comment:

Add a reference to `System.Core`